# How to disable only the question indentation and keep the parts and subparts indentation

Tags: indentation, exam

I've been using the Exam package for my answering my problem sets, that's going good.

The exam package indents all the questions for some reason, because my document is only questions, it makes the margins look uneven. I have disable the question margin using the technique from the documentation:

```latex
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}
}
```

This works but this disables the indentation for the questions, parts and subparts. This results in some of the parts being misaligned from the rest.

[image]